# Expansion of $(a+b+c+d)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to expand when $(a+b+c+d)^n$?

Can I allow it to be $[(a+b)+(c+d)]^n$ and then use binomial theorem to expand it?

Comment: Yes you can. Also refer the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. Note:

$$(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^m=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n=m}\frac{m!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}\prod_{1\leq t\leq m}x_t^{k_t}.$$